# Why is my player getting stuck in walls Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm making a game in unity 2d and when my player goes in to a wall he gets stuck and can't move at all. Here is a video:

[VIDEO](http://%3Ciframe%20width=%22560%22%20height=%22315%22%20src=%22https://www.youtube.com/embed/VaZMYruFUcg%22%20frameborder=%220%22%20allow=%22accelerometer;%20autoplay;%20encrypted-media;%20gyroscope;%20picture-in-picture%22%20allowfullscreen%3E%3C/iframe%3E)

I've tried using a composite collider, physics material with friction at 0.

Here is my movement script:

```cs
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 pos;
    float speed = 2.0f;
    private Animator animator;
    void Start()
    {
        pos = transform.position;
        animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && transform.position == pos)
        {        // Up
            animator.SetInteger("isWalking", 1);
            pos += Vector3.up;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && transform.position == pos)
        {        // Down
            animator.SetInteger("isWalking", 2);
            pos += Vector3.down;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && transform.position == pos)
        {        // Right
            animator.SetInteger("isWalking", 3);
            pos += Vector3.right;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && transform.position == pos)
        {        // Left
            animator.SetInteger("isWalking", 4);
            pos += Vector3.left;
        }
        if (Input.anyKey == false)
            animator.SetInteger("isWalking", 0);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, pos, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your video link seems to be broken; Can you edit the link with a correct version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Nitro557 i had a new idea instead of basicly teleporting the player around i used a whole different method of moving the player here is the script:

```cs
    public float runSpeed = 2.0f;
    private Rigidbody2D body;
    private Animator animator;
    private float horizontal;
    private float vertical;
    private float moveLimiter = 0.7f;
    void Start()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            runSpeed += 0.5f;
        }
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (horizontal != 0 && vertical != 0)
        {
            horizontal *= moveLimiter;
            vertical *= moveLimiter;
        }
        body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * runSpeed, vertical * runSpeed);
        // Up
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            animator.SetInteger("isWalking", 1);
        // Down
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            animator.SetInteger("isWalking", 2);
        // Right
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            animator.SetInteger("isWalking", 3);
        // Left
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            animator.SetInteger("isWalking", 4);
        if (Input.anyKeyDown == false)
            animator.SetInteger("isWalking", 0);
        body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * runSpeed, vertical * runSpeed);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Player object in your case contains a Rigidbody component. So, it would be better to use some of Rigidbody's movement methods like `MovePosition()` instead of changing position of GameObject directly via `transform.position`

Comment: Thanks i didn't use MovePosition() but i used a different method thanks